# Python - Object oriented function in tkinter with event of click

Tags: python, events, tkinter, self

my program should after click roll dice - it use six images of dice, with one, two, three, four, five and six dots. First is showed image with one dot and than after click on the image should randomly change 8 times. In the end, last random image should stay on screen, but it doesn't work and I am not able to solve it. Any idea how to fix it please?
(I know that 3 classes are not necessary for this, but i will continue in it when I'll have soluted this problem)
Thanks

```
import tkinter, random

class Main:
    def __init__(self, area, dice):
        dice.throw(area)

class Area:

    def __init__(self):
        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=1000, height=600)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.dice1 = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='numberOne.png')
        self.canvas.create_image(680,540,image=self.dice1)
        self.canvas.bind('<Button-1>', Dice.throw)

class Dice:

    def throw(event):
        if event.x < 730 and event.x > 630 and event.y < 590 and event.y > 490:
            dice1 = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='numberOne.png')
            dice2 = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='numberTwo.png')
            dice3 = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='numberThree.png')
            dice4 = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='numberFour.png')
            dice5 = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='numberFive.png')
            dice6 = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='numberSix.png')
            for i in range(8):
                number = random.randrange(6) + 1
                if number == 1:
                    area.canvas.create_image(680,540,image=dice1)
                elif number == 2:
                    area.canvas.create_image(680,540,image=dice2)
                elif number == 3:
                    area.canvas.create_image(680,540,image=dice3)               
                elif number == 4:
                    area.canvas.create_image(680,540,image=dice4)       
                elif number == 5:
                    area.canvas.create_image(680,540,image=dice5)
                elif number == 6:
                    area.canvas.create_image(680,540,image=dice6)
                area.canvas.after(100)
                area.canvas.update()

pl = Area()
dice = Dice()
main = Main(pl, dice)
```

Comment: Please provide how exactly your code doesn't work. Paste the error if any.

Comment: I don't know how to connect the event of click with appearing of pictures in random order

Comment: you have to use it with class instance - `bind('<Button-1>', dice.throw)` - so you have to use after you create `Dice`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that `Area` instance (`pl`) need access to `Dice` instance (`dice`) and `Dice` instance needs access to `Area` instance.

```
dice = Dice(root)
area = Area(root, dice) # `Area` gets access to `Dice` instace
dice.area = area        # `Dive` gets access to `Area` instace
```

after that `Dice` can use `dice.throw` and `Dice` can use `area.canvas` or other elements.

To make it simpler I assign tag to image on canvas and then I can use `tag_bind` to assign `<Button-1>` and I don't have to check `event.x`, `event.y`.

Instead of creating new image with `create_image` I change image in existing element on cavas.

`create_image()` gives element ID

```
self.image_id = self.canvas.create_image(...)
```

so later I can change image in this element

```
self.canvas.itemconfig(self.image_id, image=image)
```

I keep all images on list so I don't need all variables `dice1`, `dice2`, etc. and I can get image using index instead of `if/elif`. I can also use `random.choice(self.images)` to get random element from list.

```
image = random.choice(self.images)
```

Full code:

```
import tkinter
import random

class Main:

    def __init__(self, area, dice):
        dice.throw(area)

class Area:

    def __init__(self, master, dice):
        self.master = master
        
        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(master, width=1000, height=600)
        self.canvas.pack()
        
        self.image = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='numberOne.png')
        self.image_id = self.canvas.create_image(680, 540, image=self.image, tags='tag_image')
        
        self.canvas.tag_bind('tag_image', '<Button-1>', dice.throw)

    def change_image(self, image):
        print('changing image')
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.image_id, image=image)
        
class Dice:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.area = None # assign later
        
        self.images = [        
            tkinter.PhotoImage(file='numberOne.png')
            tkinter.PhotoImage(file='numberTwo.png')
            tkinter.PhotoImage(file='numberThree.png')
            tkinter.PhotoImage(file='numberFour.png')
            tkinter.PhotoImage(file='numberFive.png')
            tkinter.PhotoImage(file='numberSix.png')
        ]
        
    def throw(self, event):
        if self.area:
            for i in range(8):
                image = random.choice(self.images)
            
                self.area.change_image(image)
            
                self.master.update()
                self.master.after(100)
            
# --- main ---
       
root = tkinter.Tk()

dice = Dice(root)
area = Area(root, dice)
dice.area = area

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *


class GUI(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("600x750")
        self.title("Calculator")

        self.scvalue = StringVar()
        self.scvalue.set("")
        self.screen = Entry(textvar=self.scvalue,font=("Impact",30,"bold"),relief="groove")
        self.screen.pack(fill=X,ipadx=8, pady=10, padx=10)

        self.frame = Frame(self, bg="grey")
        self.frame.pack()
        # First row
        self.button = Button(self.frame,text="9", padx="15",font=("Impact",30,"bold"),bd=10,relief="groove")
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=3)
        self.button.bind("<Button-1>",self.click)
        
        self.button = Button(self.frame,text="8", padx="15",font=("Impact",30,"bold"),bd=10,relief="groove")
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=3)
        self.button.bind("<Button-1>",self.click)
        
        self.button = Button(self.frame,text="7", padx="15",font=("Impact",30,"bold"),bd=10,relief="groove")
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=3)
        self.button.bind("<Button-1>",self.click)
      
        self.frame = Frame(self, bg="grey")
        self.frame.pack()
        #second row
        self.button = Button(self.frame,text="6", padx="15",font=("Impact",30,"bold"),bd=10,relief="groove")
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=3)
        self.button.bind("<Button-1>",self.click)

        self.button = Button(self.frame,text="5", padx="15",font=("Impact",30,"bold"),bd=10,relief="groove")
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=3)
        self.button.bind("<Button-1>",self.click)

        self.button = Button(self.frame,text="4", padx="15",font=("Impact",30,"bold"),bd=10,relief="groove")
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=3)
        self.button.bind("<Button-1>",self.click)

        self.frame = Frame(self, bg="grey")
        self.frame.pack()
        #third row
        self.button = Button(self.frame,text="3", padx="15",font=("Impact",30,"bold"),bd=10,relief="groove")
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT,padx=7,pady=3)
        self.button.bind("<Button-1>",self.click)
        
        self.button = Button(self.frame,text="2", padx="15",font=("Impact",30,"bold"),bd=10,relief="groove")
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT,padx=7,pady=3)
        self.button.bind("<Button-1>",self.click)
        
        self.button = Button(self.frame,text="1", padx="15",font=("Impact",30,"bold"),bd=10,relief="groove")
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT,padx=7,pady=3)
        self.button.bind("<Button-1>",self.click)
        
        self.frame = Frame(self, bg="grey")
        self.frame.pack()
        #fourth row
        self.button = Button(self.frame,text="0", padx="15",font=("Impact",30,"bold"),bd=10,relief="groove")
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=3)
        self.button.bind("<Button-1>",self.click)
       
        self.button = Button(self.frame,text="00", padx="15",font=("Impact",30,"bold"),bd=10,relief="groove")
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=3)
        self.button.bind("<Button-1>",self.click)
        
        self.button = Button(self.frame,text=".", padx="15",font=("Impact",30,"bold"),bd=10,relief="groove")
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=3)
        self.button.bind("<Button-1>",self.click)
        
        self.frame = Frame(self, bg="grey")
        self.frame.pack()
        #fifth row
        self.button = Button(self.frame,text="+", padx="15",font=("Impact",30,"bold"),bd=10,relief="groove")
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT,padx=10,pady=3)
        self.button.bind("<Button-1>",self.click)
        
        self.button = Button(self.frame,text="-", padx="15",font=("Impact",30,"bold"),bd=10,relief="groove")
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT,padx=10,pady=3)
        self.button.bind("<Button-1>",self.click)
        
        self.button = Button(self.frame,text="*", padx="15",font=("Impact",30,"bold"),bd=10,relief="groove")
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT,padx=10,pady=3)
        self.button.bind("<Button-1>",self.click)
        
        self.frame = Frame(self, bg="grey")
        self.frame.pack()
        #sixth row
        self.button = Button(self.frame,text="%", padx="15",font=("Impact",30,"bold"),bd=10,relief="groove")
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=3)
        self.button.bind("<Button-1>",self.click)
        
        self.button = Button(self.frame,text="C", padx="15",font=("Impact",30,"bold"),bd=10,relief="groove")
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=3)
        self.button.bind("<Button-1>",self.click)
        
        self.button = Button(self.frame,text="=", padx="15",font=("Impact",30,"bold"),bd=10,relief="groove")
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=3)
        self.button.bind("<Button-1>",self.click)
        

    def click(self,event):
        self.text = event.widget.cget("text")
        if self.text == '=':
            if self.scvalue.get().isdigit():
                self.value=self.scvalue.get()
            else:
                try:
                    #eval => evauluate expression
                    self.value = eval(self.screen.get())
                    self.scvalue.set(self.value)
                    self.screen.update()
                except Exception as e:
                    self.scvalue.set("Error....")
                    self.screen.update()
            pass
        elif self.text=='C':
            self.scvalue.set("")
            self.screen.update()

        else:
            self.scvalue.set(self.scvalue.get()+self.text)
            self.screen.update()

root = GUI()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. An answer that consists of > 150 lines of code would be much more useful to everyone if it included an explanation of what it did and how it solves the problem. Could you please [edit] your answer to add some more information.